# $.each strange index when only one exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml

**Background**

My data was originally XML but I have converted it to JSON using [this function](https://jsfiddle.net/hj0szh65/).  I've been writing some tests and functions on single elements without issue, but I got to an element that has a sibling with the same name, so I wrote the following code:

```
$.each(jdoc.ClinicalDocument.templateId, function (i, v) {
    doStuff(v);
});
```

**Working Scenario**

This works great when there are 2 or more `templateId` elements, as expected the i variable is 0, 1, etc, etc. Also, the "v" object looks as it should:

[image]

**Error Scenario**

However, when there is only one instance of `templateId` things look different:

[image]

**Question**

What can I do differently so that I get the same behavior for 1 or multiple instances of the specified element?  If I'll have to do a check first, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying size and length I realized those don't work on non-arrays, which led me to `isArray()`:

```
if ($.isArray(jdoc.ClinicalDocument.templateId)) { 
  //$.each here
} else {
  //singular handler here
}
```